# Datadog monitoring Disk usage

Tags: amazon-ec2, datadog

I want to use datadog for monitoring my EC2 Instance Disk utilization and create alerts for it. I am using system.disk.in_use metric but I am not getting my root mount point in from sectionavg:system.disk.in_use{device:/dev/loop0} by {host} and my root mount point is /dev/root. I can see every loop mount point in the list but can't see the root. due to this, the data I am getting in the monitor is different than the actual server, for example, df -hT is showing 99% root in the server but on datadog monitoring it is showing 60%.
I am not too familiar with how to use datadog, can someone please help?

Try to research about it but not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: At first glance it seems like a permissions issue. Does the user running `dd-agent` have access to `/dev/root`?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use the device label to read in only the root volume such as:

> avg:system.disk.in_use{device_label:/} by {host}

I personally found the metric `system.disk.in_use` to equal the total and instead added a formula that calculated the utilization using `system.disk.total` and `system.disk.free` to be more accurate.